Slowdown when scrolling Steam library because of icons and titles loading
I've been dealing with this annoying thing for years now. There is a slowdown when scrolling through Steam library when you open it. It seems like it happens because Steam loads icons and game titles, and then forgets them after some time. When they're loaded, there is no slowdown. Is there a way to force Steam to remember icons and titles indefinitely? I feel like there should be a fix since it's been a problem for a long time.
There's an option disable icons, but I want to keep them.
Demonstration

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
